# spring bean issue with Set property

Tags: java, spring

I have bean e.g.

```
<bean id="manager" class="com.Manager" init-method="init">
       <property name="services">
        <set>
            <ref bean="service" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myService"
        class="com.MyService" abstract="true">
</bean>

<bean id="service" class="com.SpecificService" parent="myService">

</bean>
```

service(SpecificService) is class which extends abstract class MyService with abstract method init()
and implement interface MyInterface with method specificLogic().

So, manager calls method init() on service object like this:

```
private Set<MyService> services;

public void init() {

    for (MyService service : services) {
        service.init();
    }



}
```

But I have following problem when bean is initializing:

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashSet'
>    to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'services'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108 implementing com.MyInterface,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.MyService] for property 'services[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found.

Comment: Use util namespace and create a util:set bean. Refer [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-set)

Comment: Is the same problem. Problem is in extending abstract class and implementing another interface.

Comment: That is not a problem with `Set` and `LinkedHashSet`. It is about `com.MyInterface,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy` and `com.MyService`. Show us the AOP part of your code.

Comment: I don't have AOP part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have posted all your config?
Because there is some AOP "hidden" (maybe by annotations) code around because `service` bean is proxied.
You have to choice:

1. Change declaration of `private Set<MyService> services` to `private Set services
2. In your AOP code let the proxy expose the target-class (`MyService`) and not the interface (`MyInterface`)

Check your code

Comment: I use only these annotations: "@Override" "@Transactional"

Comment: I don't understand why can't use MyService, because in Manager I would like to see only init() method. Why have spring problem with this?

Comment: @Transactional make proxies and a JDK proxy expose interfaces (MyInterface) and not implementations (MyService). Look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953572/introducer-aspect-in-spring/17954492#17954492) answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to initialize your Set services for the initialization.

You just declared it as

```
private Set<MyService> services;
```

It just considers the interface Set and in your bean configuration it seems like by default the set is a LinkedHashSet.

So you can try to initialize your Set services like :

```
 private Set<MyService> services = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Comment: Still the same, I think that problem is with inheritence abstract class a implementation of interface. Because in Manager class I use only abstract class type.